# What is the origin of the phrase "circular firing squad"?

Tags: etymology, slang, phrase-origin, politics

I've found many definitions online of the term, which the OED says is "used in reference to a situation in which a group of people are engaged in self-destructive internal conflicts and mutual recriminations," but I haven't been able to find any discussion of its origin.

Comment: Pretty sure I heard "circular firing squad" in high school, in the 60.

Comment: "Do not attempt to move or we'll be shooting ourselves."

Comment: While not an identical concept, when the ill-fated Jewish AD 70 revolt against the Romans failed, and the Romans were about to capture a group of soldiers, the ancient Jewish historian Josephus wrote that the soldiers (Josephus amongst them) formed a circle and killed each other (until only Josephus and another remained). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem
This is a rather famous historic event, and I speculate, without evidence, it may have contributed to the imagery of a circular firing squad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea, though not quite the exact term, appeared in *Time* magazine in 1972, as quoted in an Alabama newspaper:

> After the calamity at the 1968 convention in Chicago, with street fighting upstaging floor fighting, the party decided on a reform movement that would bring more people into the nominating process.
>
> The many primaries with a full platoon of candidates was one result of this reformation, with results best described by a one-liner in *Time* magazine:
>
> 'When reform-minded Democrats are told make up a firing squad they form a circle.'

-- "As O'Brien Sees It." *Montgomery Advertiser*, April 9, 1972, p4

Answer (score 10):

OED—"September 2020 draft addition" under *circular*:

> **circular firing squad**  n. originally and chiefly *U.S.* a group of people who are engaged in self-destructive internal conflicts and
> mutual recriminations; (also) a situation, event, etc., characterized
> by this kind of behaviour.
>
> **1973**   Let. in *Las Vegas* (New Mexico) *Optic* 23 Mar. 2/1   It is imperative that if we do not integrate we must—at the
> least—synchronize our lives; otherwise we will form a circular firing
> squad in which members of the squad will kill all that is worthwhile
> within the circle as well as themselves in the cross-fire.

This letter in the *Las Vegas Optic* could be the first use in print, or at least close to it in time, given that the writer explains the expression. I haven't found anything earlier in Google Books.

Comment: In the late 70s, I repeatedly heard US kids exchange this joke as "Have you heard about the <targeted group> firing squad?  All in a circle."  Bit like the still current "How many <x> does it take to screw in a light bulb.".

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Oh wow, I now remember that as one of many Polish jokes heard in grade school. This would be in the *early* 70's.

Answer (score 7):

According to Etymonline:

> The metaphoric circular firing squad is attested by 1990.

Actually its usage appears to have been in place at least from the ‘80s

From: [City Problems](https://books.google.it/books?id=0VKOAAAAMAAJ&q=%22circular%20firing%20squad%22&dq=%22circular%20firing%20squad%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvgfzsw471AhWSzqQKHRzRAdw4ChDoAXoECAcQAw) The Annual Proceedings of the United States Conference of Mayors - 1983:

> You can easily come away with the impression that our national drug policy is being formulated by a circular firing squad ....

From: [Savings Institutions, Volume 109](https://books.google.it/books?id=_n0WAQAAMAAJ&q=%22circular%20firing%20squad%22&dq=%22circular%20firing%20squad%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvgfzsw471AhWSzqQKHRzRAdw4ChDoAXoECAIQAw). United States League of Savings Institutions, 1988 :

> …the private mortgage insurance business has been like a circular firing squad , ” says Maurice R. Greenberg , president and chief executive officer of American ...